# How can I change precedence behavior of CSS to stop overriding css classes?

Tags: html, css

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="role" id="role1" class="margin-class" checked="checked">

input[type="checkbox"] {
    height: 1.42857em;
    margin-bottom: 1.42857em;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}

.margin-class {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Both these css comes from bundle.css where I am not allowed to make any change. But I want to apply margin class necessarily. Here selector css is overriding class css. I know the rule of 
precedence where selector css has more precedence. But is there anyway by which I can override
the rule. I am not allowed to use local css too and not allowed to make any changes like       !important and all.

Comment: I mentioned I cannot use !important

Comment: are inline styles an option?

Comment: No, Sorry for these many restrictions.

Comment: then my friend youre Stuck

Comment: Yes, Anonymous Friend!! Thats why I came here and asked the question!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the bundled CSS or supply your own stylesheet, your only recourse is using an inline style attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="role" id="role1" style="margin-bottom: 0" checked="checked">
```

Or applying the style using JavaScript, if you can't modify the HTML either.

If you can't do *any* of these things, then you're pretty much stuck. If that rule is intended to apply to certain elements with the class, then the bundled CSS was poorly written. You can't change how the cascade works other than by using the features given to you (and even then it's not really changing how it works).

Comment: We generally don't supply any local styles. I have tried this. Its working but not acceptable.

Comment: :) :) Thanks . I will think of your suggestion soon.

Comment: @LearningCoding: Let's make this simple: *What **are** you allowed to do?*

Comment: @jbutler483 I am allowed to add some html above and below checkbox. I am allowed to change checkbox into some other control. and in the html I will add I can use margin-class

Comment: You've ruled out every possible way of adding styling to the element: Adding a css file, adding local css, adding inline css + adding css via jquery. What you've pretty much asked is 'How to add a style without adding any styling'. @LearningCoding

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0opbcmz/). Click the button. I have used java script to make the changes.

```
document.getElementById('role1').style.top ='50px'
```

You can put all such changes in a function, then call the function on window Load (There is no need for the button, just for illustration only). Hope this helps.

Comment: Man , Its same as applying local css. Sorry I think there is no solutions . Better I will remove this question. I dnt think it will be possible to change precedence any how.

Comment: It has the same effect as applying local css. But reading your question made me think that, you were not allowed to touch CSS. Anyway I just gave it a shot.

Answer (score -3):

You can be bit more specific like providing id's to the selector and providing it the styles!!

Comment: try adding inline code as , "margin-bottom:0 !important " for the checkbox

Comment: since you told you cannot add inline style use javascript or jquery to add style like role1.style.margin-bottom = '0';